# Pagination with joins and where clauses on them

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, pagination

**The problem**

Imagine having a table full of articles. Each article has one author and can have many tags.

When fetching those articles, there should have the tags + author on them.

This is achieved by joining the tags and author on the articles table.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM article
LEFT JOIN tag ON article.id = tag.article_id
```

---

But now I want to implement pagination.

**What I've tried**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM article
LEFT JOIN tag ON article.id = tag.article_id
LIMIT 7
```

But now, what if I have an article with 6 tags and one with 3? I get the one article with all 6 tags, but the other article with just one tag.

I've read some blog posts because of I got stuck.

When I limited the rows, I lose data.

Now I've read to do separate requests. But first of all, I only want to do **one** query and more importantly I want to filter my queries. E.g.: Return all articles with a certain tag, but use pagination.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM article
LEFT JOIN tag ON article.id = tag.article_id
WHERE tag.name = "TV Show"
LIMIT 7
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add your current query and example of data (as text!)

Comment: You can get all of the data with a single query to the database or you can issue multiple queries to retrieve the data in pages: the two are mutually exclusive. It is not "the nature of SQL" to lose data. If expected data is missing from the result set, then the probable cause is either it doesn't exist in the database, or the query is defective.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Do you need all the information from tag table, and one tag per row? Or would list of tags concatenated by comma in a single row would be sufficient?

Comment: I actually need one tag per row. @markalex

Comment: @DevOskar, then you'll need to do it in to separate requests: 1. list of articles from page, 2. List of tags per article from 1.

Comment: Ok, but I want to query based on tags and let's say the article name, how can I do that then? @markalex

Comment: Please provide an example of the source data and the desired output. Descriptions are not sufficient.

Comment: There are three things needed to meaningfully paginate query results: an `ORDER BY` guaranteeing a deterministic order, an `OFFSET` to determine the first row of the results to be returned, and a `LIMIT` to set the maximum number of rows to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need full information on tags associated with articles, you'll need
to do it in two step:

1. Query list of articles for desired page employing your filters. Something like

```sql
SELECT *
FROM article a
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM tag t
  WHERE a.id = t.article_id
  and t.name = :p_tag)
AND a.name like '%'||:p_article_name||'%'
ORDER BY a.publish_date
LIMIT 7
```

2. Select list of tags for articles from step 1. Something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tag t
WHERE t.article_id in (:p1, :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7)
```

Where `:pN` is a corresponding article id.

---

Alternatively you can do it in a single query, combining those two steps:

```sql
WITH articles_page(
  SELECT *
  FROM article a
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tag t
    WHERE a.id = t.article_id
    and t.name = :p_tag)
  AND a.name like '%'||:p_article_name||'%'
  ORDER BY a.publish_date
  LIMIT 7 
)
select * 
from articles_page a
left join tags t
on (a.id = t.article_id)
```

But IMHO, it is not the best choice, as you'll need to aggregate this dataset on the application side.